# How to create a tabular report from Azure DevOps that includes work item description?

Tags: api, azure-devops, powerbi, reporting

We are trying to use PowerBi to build tabular reports from data in Azure DevOps.  In this report, we want to display the **description** field in one of the table's columns.  ADO stores the description as HTML.  Neither PowerBI or Excel can render this content, but instead show the markup code.  I've also looked at pulling this into python and using Dash with no luck.

There is an extension for ADO that renders html, but it displays a single record and doesn't work as a table cell renderer.

The output I'm looking for is very simple.  It is a table (preferably in PowerBI or some other dashboarding tool) that has columns for work item title and description.  The description column shows the rendered HTML code as it is displayed in ADO.

Answer (score 1):

> How to create a tabular report from Azure DevOps that includes work
>   item description?

For this issue, I am afraid this demand is impossible to achieve. It is clearly stated in the document that **Description** field cannot be used to generate a report.Excel also does not support generating reports on this field.

[image]

For details,please refer to this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/excel/create-status-and-trend-excel-reports?view=azure-devops-2019). Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Hugh, yeah we know that you can't report on these fields out of the box.  We're looking for a way to do it outside of normal MS channels.  We're also trying to contact ADO product management to see what they recommend.